# Directive is being rendered before promise is resolved

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am having issues getting my directive to render its content only after my promise has been resolved. I thought `then()` was supposed to do this but it doesn't seem to be working..

Here is my controller:

```
// Generated by CoffeeScript 1.6.3
(function() {
  var sprangularControllers;

  sprangularControllers = angular.module('sprangularControllers', ['sprangularServices', 'ngRoute']);

  sprangularControllers.controller('productsController', [
    '$scope', '$route', '$routeParams', 'Product', 'Taxonomy', function($scope, $route, $routeParams, Product, Taxonomy) {
      Taxonomy.taxonomies_with_meta().$promise.then(function(response) {
        return $scope.taxonomies = response.taxonomies;
      });
      return Product.find($routeParams.id).$promise.then(function(response) {
        return $scope.currentProduct = response;
      });
    }
  ]);

}).call(this);
```

My directive:

```
// Generated by CoffeeScript 1.6.3
(function() {
  var sprangularDirectives;

  sprangularDirectives = angular.module('sprangularDirectives', []);

  sprangularDirectives.directive('productDirective', function() {
    return {
      scope: {
        product: '='
      },
      templateUrl: 'partials/product/_product.html',
      link: function(scope, el, attrs) {
        console.log(scope);
        console.log(scope.product);
        return el.text(scope.product.name);
      }
    };
  });

}).call(this);
```

Scope returns okay, and when I check it in dev tools `scope.product` is not undefined however I am presuming that is because by the time I check it the promise has been resolved?

`console.log(scope.product)` however, returns undefined..

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Because your value is asynchronously populated, you'll want to add a watch function that updates your bound element.

```
  link: function(scope, el, attrs) {
    scope.$watch('product', function(newVal) {
        if(newVal) { el.text(scope.product.name);}
    }, true);
  }
```

You could also move a lot of complexity into a directive controller and use the link function for manipulating the DOM only.

The `true` third parameter to `$watch` causes a deep watch, since you're binding this directive to a model.

Here are a couple of links with good examples:
 http://www.ng-newsletter.com/posts/directives.html
http://seanhess.github.io/2013/10/14/angularjs-directive-design.html

Comment: Thanks Jim, does that mean that its simply the isolate scope that isn't being updated? Using a watch did cross my mind but I didnt see any examples online, so I presumed it wasn't the 'angular way'...hoping that's not the case, will give this a go and report back.

Comment: I don't understand your question. Directives are all just nested scopes within your controller's scope. If you don't explicitly define a scope, angular creates one. It also creates watches for you in the background (like when you do `{{project.name}}`), so I'd say the watch is the most angular way. Also, [Mastering Web Application Development with AngularJS | Packt Publishing](http://bit.ly/1deKEKU) is a good book.

Comment: If anyone comes by this. That $watch could also be in the parent controller as well. Since the directive is bound to the same scope value. Also if you have a watch on an object that gets a new object dot notated value then you should check if it exists in the watch as well.

Answer (score 82):

As stated in [an official thread about this issue](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/2095#issuecomment-45448581) (quickly closed as "won't fix because it would make directives wait"), a workaround is to wrap your directive in a `ng-if` :

```
<div ng-if="myPromiseParam">
  <my-directive param="myPromiseParam">
</div>
```

Comment: Ahhh sooo much easier to fix the problem

Comment: For the sake of performance, don't forget to use bind-once syntax (ng-if="::myPromiseParam") if you know it won't change.

Comment: This should accepted instead of using of accepted one that using watch.

Answer (score 24):

I know this is an older question, but thought I would try my hand at providing an updated answer.

When using a router, both ui-router and ngRouter have resolve methods that will resolve promises on url changes before switching to that route and rendering things on the page.

[ngRouter Resolve tutorial](http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2014/05/20/using-resolve-in-angularjs-routes.aspx)
[ui-router Resolve docs](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki#resolve)

Another option, instead of using `$watch` is to use angulars [`$q` promise library](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q).
More specifically, the `$q.when()` method. This takes promises and values. IF it's a promise it will fire a `.then()` when the promise resolves. If its a value, it wraps it in a promise and immediately resolves it.

```
link: function(scope, el, attrs){
    $q.when(scope.product).then(function(product){
        scope.product = product;
        el.text(scope.product.name);
    });
}
```

Or there a couple way you can not show anything just with html.

```
<product-directive product='object'>
    <!-- Will hide span until product.name exists -->
    <span ng-show='product.name'>{{ product.name }}</span> 

    <!-- Will show default text until key exists -->
    {{ product.name || 'Nothing to see here' }}

    <!-- Will show nothing until key exists -->
    <span ng-bind='product.name'></span>
</product-directive>
```

Answer (score 0):

use $watch on your variable in your directive to get the updated value of your variable.

you can also make use of $q to resolve the promise.