# Can't access attr data in angular custom directive link function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, d3.js

I'm trying to access attr data defined by a controller in a custom directive's link function.

Here is some simple angular markup:

```
<div class='barChart'>
  {{vm.totals}}
  <bar-chart chart-data='vm.totals'></bar-chart
</div>
```

This is the directive defintion:

```
angular
    .module('app')
    .directive('barChart', [Callback])

function Callback() {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      replace: false,
      scope: {data: '=chartData'},
      link: (scope, el, attrs) => {
        console.log(scope);
        console.log(el);
        console.log(attrs.chartData);
      }
    }
}
```

When I log scope, I can see the data array in this object as expected, heres a picture: 
[image]

As you can see the data is the 10 item array at the bottom. The array also shows up in the browser, so the data is there. However, as soon as I change the `console.log` to log that property:

```
console.log(scope.data)
```

The value that gets printed is undefined. I'm trying to access the data in the link function so that I can use d3 to create a visualization. The data is there, but it's undefined as soon as I call `.data` on scope. Any ideas?

Comment: or any ideas to not use scope and get the attr data from the directive in the html?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use $watch to log the data:

```
angular
    .module('app')
    .directive('barChart', [Callback])

function Callback() {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      replace: false,
      scope: {data: '=chartData'},
      link: (scope, el, attrs) => {
        console.log(scope);
        console.log(el);
        console.log(attrs.chartData);
        //USE $watch
        scope.$watch("data", function(value) {
          console.log(value);
        });
      }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can access `vm.totals` as scope variable but passed as attribute:

```
scope: {
  chartData: '='  //@ reads the attribute value
}
```

And in your html:

```
<bar-chart chart-data='vm.totals'></bar-chart>
```

Now in link function you can access it:

```
console.log(scope.chartData);
```

Note that this is one way binding, so if you need two way you need to use `=` instead.

Update:

If you are using async call you need to use two way binding or watch for the changes in your link function:

```
scope.$watch('chartData', function(newVal) {
    if(newVal) {  console.log(scope.chartData) }
}, true);
```

Note that since it is an array it is better to use collection watch (true as the last arg).

Comment: that binds the string literal `'vm.totals'` to chartData not the data from the controller.

Comment: sorry forgot to put interpolation in html @AndrewKim check the update

Comment: that .. sort of works. It makes it so i see a string of the array data. But i'm running into the same sort of problem, where i can see it fine when i `console.log(scope)`. As soon as I `console.log(scope.chartData)` it logs an empty string =(

Comment: it has to be that the data isn't there yet.. or something

Comment: I think it has to do with the async call I'm making to a csv file through a service to get the data.

Comment: that explains it, you need to use promise and resolve

Comment: Yeah, thats gotta be it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21177582/directive-is-being-rendered-before-promise-is-resolved is exactly what's happening to me. If you update your answer with what we've talked about I'll give ya the check. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

use `@` in the link function to have one way binding to the controller.

```js
angular
    .module('app', [])
.controller('ctrl', function($scope){$scope.totals="1234";})
    .directive('barChart', [Callback])

function Callback() {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      replace: false,
      scope: {data: '@'},
      link: function(scope, el, attrs) {
        console.log(attrs.chartData);
      }
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
<div class='barChart'>
  {{totals}}
  <bar-chart chart-data='{{totals}}'></bar-chart>
</div>
  </div>
```

Comment: `@` is attribute binding. one-way binding is `<`.